# Is Target always an Entity or can it be EntityReference?

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I discovered that in some of my code I have the following syntax guarding the plugin from FUBARing. I can't for the love of god not remember why I put the disjuction conditional for *EntityReference*.

Is *Context.InputParameters["Target"]* every *EntityReference*?

```
bool goodToGo 
  = Context.InputParameters.Contains("Target")
    && Context.PrimaryEntityName == "email";
    && (
      Context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity
      || Context.InputParameters["Target"] is EntityReference);
```

Is it ever **anything** other than *Entity*?

Comment: there are a couple of other things it can be as well - I did have a list somewhere. Now if only I could remember where...

Answer (score 10):

Target can be also an EntityReference, from MSDN:

> Note that not all requests contain a Target property that is of type Entity, so you do have to look at each individual request or response. For example, DeleteRequest does have a Target property but its type is EntityReference.

[Understand the Data Context Passed to a Plug-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309673.aspx#bkmk_inputandoutput)

So depending on the logic of your plugin you may need to check the property type also for *EntityReference*.

Comment: Of course... **Now** I remember - I had the issue when operating on removal of entities. Very good answer: +1.